# How to add Buttons to a iOS 14 Widget

Tags: ios, swift, widget, swiftui, ios14

I'm trying to add buttons to a widget having family type ".systemLarge". I want to execute some code without opening the app.

Anyone knows how to do that?

For example the Shortcuts App Widget includes buttons you can tap to execute a shortcut without opening the app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556274/ios-add-button-to-widget-extension/66006151#66006151

Comment: This is now possible in iOS 17! Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77190038/1759443

Answer (score 7):

Widgets are read only. The Shortcuts app is an exception.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension

> Widgets present read-only information and don’t support interactive elements such as scrolling elements or switches. WidgetKit omits interactive elements when rendering a widget’s content.

Comment: ok I wasn't sure because they don't explicitly mention buttons in that hint. And yes of course because of the Shortcuts App Widget. But that isn’t the first time that their own apps don’t fulfill the Guidelines.

Comment: I added buttons to iOS 13 widget & there was no limitation or issues with that!

Comment: Yup. The old style widgets could support buttons. The new iOS 14 widgets can’t.

Comment: Maps app uses buttons inside widget. So it's possible in some way.

Comment: Yes Maps has 2 butons but they open the app. Then an action is done thanks to widgetUrl being set on each button. When the app opens, it's onOpenUrl() doing the necessary check to do the appropriate action. Wasted a day figuring all that... I need a button to simply have the numbers on widget go from friendly display(k,M,B) to full numbers.

Answer (score 7):

You can add Link controls on medium and large size widgets to get a button like behavior.

This won't allow you to create interactive widgets, which change their content by clicking elements inside the widgets.
But you will be able to tell which "link" was clicked based on the widgetUrl provided when your app gets activated through the widget.

See the chapter *Respond to User Interactions* here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension

Comment: seems to only support one url per widget, so no way to tell where unfortunately, still cool

Answer (score 1):

### This is now available in iOS 17!

[Details here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/adding-interactivity-to-widgets-and-live-activities)

> Starting with iOS 17, iPadOS 17, or macOS 14, widgets and Live Activities can include buttons and toggles to offer specific app functionality without launching the app
>
> For example, a Reminders widget allows people to mark a task as completed with a toggle. On a locked device, buttons and toggles are inactive and the system doesn’t perform actions unless a person authenticates and unlocks their device.

#### Add the functionality as an intent

1. Create a struct

   - For Widget, adopt the `AppIntent` protocol
   - For Live Activity, adopt the `LiveActivityIntent` protocol
2. For input parameters, define via the `@Parameter` property wrapper (this has to conform to `AppEntity`)
3. In `perform()` function, add the action you want to perform on click

Example:

```swift
@available(iOS 16.0, macOS 13.0, watchOS 9.0, tvOS 16.0, *)
struct SuperCharge: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Emoji Ranger SuperCharger"
    static var description = IntentDescription("All heroes get instant 100% health.")
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        EmojiRanger.superchargeHeros()
        return .result()
    }
}
```

Notes

- The `perform()` function is asynchronous AND marked as throws.
- When you return from the perform() function, the system reloads the widget’s timeline (via timeline provider).

#### Add the button

```swift
struct EmojiRangerWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleEntry
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        switch family {
        
        // Code for other widget sizes.
           
        case .systemLarge:
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Button(intent: SuperCharge()) {
                        Image(systemName: "bolt.fill")
                    }
                }
                .tint(.white)
                .padding()
            }
            // ...rest of view
       }
    }
}
```

### Pre-iOS 17 Solution

There are some limitations, but it can be done

1. You can't just execute code, you can only deeplink to your app which then handles the click.
2. `systemSmall` widget is treated as one clickable area (no granular control over multiple touch targets)
3. `systemMedium` and `systemLarge` can have more touch targets and use `Link` to deeplink to your app with a specific action.

To see an example of how this can be done, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66006151/1759443).